# Node MySQL - Edit response before sending

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm Using `Node` and `MySQL`. I'm pulling data from MySQL in Node like this:

```
app.get('/getposts', (req, res) => {
   connection.query("SELECT * FROM posts", function(err, rows, fields){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else if(rows.length) {
            res.send(rows)             // <= Edit this res before sending.
        }
        else {
            res.send('No Posts')
        }
    });
});
```

I get the following response:

```
[
 {id:1, name:'post1', desc: 'post1 desc' },
 {id:2, name:'post2', desc: 'post2 desc' },
 {id:3, name:'post3', desc: 'post3 desc' }
]
```

I want to edit the response before sending. I want the `id` to be `key` and the `value` to be the `post`. Like for 1 I want `1:{id:1, name:'post1', desc: 'post1 desc'}`. So the entire response should look like this:

```
[
  1: {id:1, name:'post1', desc: 'post1 desc' },
  2: {id:2, name:'post2', desc: 'post2 desc' },
  3: {id:3, name:'post3', desc: 'post3 desc' }
]
```

How can I achieve this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this,

```
var jsonObj = [
    {id:1, name:'post1', desc: 'post1 desc' },
    {id:2, name:'post2', desc: 'post2 desc' },
    {id:3, name:'post3', desc: 'post3 desc' }
];

var keyArr = [];

for(var index in jsonObj){
    var obj = {};
    obj[jsonObj[index].id] = jsonObj[index];
    keyArr.push(obj);

}

console.log(keyArr);
```

P.S : This is not a valid json or an array

```
[
  1: {id:1, name:'post1', desc: 'post1 desc' },
  2: {id:2, name:'post2', desc: 'post2 desc' },
  3: {id:3, name:'post3', desc: 'post3 desc' }
]
```

The best possible alternate is,

```
[ { '1': { id: 1, name: 'post1', desc: 'post1 desc' } },
  { '2': { id: 2, name: 'post2', desc: 'post2 desc' } },
  { '3': { id: 3, name: 'post3', desc: 'post3 desc' } } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var obj = [  
    {id:1, name:'post1', desc: 'post1 desc' },
    {id:2, name:'post2', desc: 'post2 desc' },
    {id:3, name:'post3', desc: 'post3 desc' }
    ];

    var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){
    var tempObject = {};
    tempObject[obj[key].id] = obj[key];
   return tempObject;
   });
```